# RDS MySQL to Kinesis data stream pipeline using AWS Lambda

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to extract data from RDS MySQL instance and load into kinesis data stream using put_record boto3 API. The connection using `pymysql` is working and I am able to print the table but, I cannot write the data into kinesis data stream. I get this error `"Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable"`.

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    connection = pymysql.connect(
    host = endpoint, 
    user = username,
    password = passwrd,
    database = database_name)
    
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10')

    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print("{0} {1} {2}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))

    kinesis = boto3.client('kinesis')

    response = kinesis.put_record(
        StreamName="test",
        Data=json.dumps(rows),
        PartitionKey="1"
    )
    
    connection.commit()
    
lambda_handler(None,None)
```

I tried printing the table and it worked. Only issue is putting records into kinesis data stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is thrown when an object with a property of type `datetime` is passed to `json.dumps` method. There are several ways on how to resolve it but the quickest one is to convert all `datetime` properties to string by using the `keyword` argument of `json.dumps`

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime

# The default keyword argument can 
# be set to a function that gets called 
# for objects that can't otherwise be serialized.
    response = kinesis.put_record(
        StreamName="test",
        Data=json.dumps(rows, default=str),
        PartitionKey="1"
    )
```